# AWS Api Gateway - Http integration client IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway as a http proxy to my rest api application.
The thing is, I can't seem to find a way to get the client ip address or to pass it through to my application from the api gateway.
The only way I saw was to use a lambda function, but I can't use it because it have to be a http integration.

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with API Gateway's HTTP APIs ([announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/) in Dec 2019), be aware of the [payload format version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html) under Advanced Settings in Integrations. You can pick between 1.0 and 2.0.

Using Kotlin code as examples, for 1.0, you can retrieve the source IP from `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` as follows.

```
event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp
```

For 2.0, you can retrieve the source IP from `APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent` as follows.

```
event.requestContext.http.sourceIp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just configure request payload-mapping. What you need is $context.identity.sourceIp. According to documentation:

> $context.identity.sourceIp
>
> The source IP address of the TCP connection making the request to API
> Gateway.

Documentation with examples is available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: I have decided to add it to my body using a mapping template. Is there a way to simply add a property to the body?

Comment: For an example of adding the sourceIp to the body using a mapping template, see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238081

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the mapping template of your integration response.  Call $context.identity.sourceIp to get the sourceIp.

If you're already using a mapping template, then you can just add this at any convenient point.  If you aren't currently using a mapping template and just need to add the sourceIp to an incoming json request body, add a mapping template like so:

```
#set($allParams = $input.path('$'))
#set($discard=$allParams.put('sourceIp', $context.identity.sourceIp))
$input.json('$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ["proxy"-style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) integration, the client IP is available inside the request (no template mapping is required). Follow the code example from the link above and dig inside "event" JSON object:

```
requestContext -> identity -> sourceIp
```